# How do I write a shell command to extract the second and second to last columns of a CSV file?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I'm using bash shell on Mac Yosemite.  I found this command for extracting the second column of a CSV file ...

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}'
```

but my quesiton is what if I want to extract both the second and second-to-last column?  For simplicity, we can assume there is more than one column in the CSV data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$(NF-1)` to get **second-to-last** column:

```
awk -F '"?,"?' '{print $2, $(NF-1)}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
    awk -F , '{print $2,$(NF-1)}' temp1.csv
```

Comment: It will fail to trim double quotes off the values if present.